# Changing ng-repeat scope in function doesn't update scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, material-design

I am using Angular Material in my App. Inside an ng-repeat List i have  fields. However i want the user to be able to add often used prefixes to the text. For example if the he wants to type "hours: 5" he can click on a button which adds "hours: " to the input field so he just has to type in 5.


This is what i have right now: HTML:

```
<md-menu>
                              <md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" class="ps-button" aria-label="Open sample menu">
                                +
                              </md-button>
                              <md-menu-content class="ps-selectcontainer">
                                <md-menu-item ng-repeat="remark in remarks"><md-button class="ps-button" ng-click="addRemark(remark, this)">{{remark}}</md-button></md-menu-item>
                              </md-menu-content>
                            </md-menu>
                          </md-input-container>
```

The Input Container:

```
<md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block" >
                            <input ng-model='form_noteName' type="text" placeholder="Note" maxlength="255" required>
                          </md-input-container>
```

And in Javascript:

```
$scope.addRemark = function (remark, repeatScope){

        if(repeatScope.form_noteName){
            repeatScope.form_noteName = remark + repeatScope.form_noteName;
             $scope.stupidvariable = repeatScope.form_noteName;
            return;
        }
        repeatScope.form_noteName = remark;
        return;
    };
```

The idea is that when i click on an item in the md-menu it opens the function addRemark passes the scope, in addRemark it modifies the scope and the input field has changed. 
But the variable form_noteName doesn't change and i don't know what i am doing wrong. What am i doing wrong here?

Edit.: Here's a Plunker with a similiar approach: http://plnkr.co/edit/1j3F64YyJPftxLf8QaZD?p=preview

Thanks :)

Comment: what is `repeatScope.form_noteName` referring to?  there aren't any properties that look like that here in this HTML.  Also, you mention an input field, but again, it doesn't look like there is an input field in your code.  anyway, why are you trying to modify an angular control structure (scope) instead of simply pushing the new `remark` into the `remarks` array?

Comment: I edited the question, t add the input container, i try this with the scope because i can't think of any other approach right now. I want the user to be able to add prewritten text to the input field

Comment: this still doesn't make sense; you are clicking on an item already in the array (being repeated) in order to add that item's text to the model of a different input that isn't inside the repeat?  that leads me further from this solution being right, since your input isn't in the scope you are trying to change....

Comment: Yes i think my solution is far from right^^. But in the addRemark Method i have access to the form_noteName. So it has to be in the same scope right? Would you have any different idea on how to approach this?

Comment: your plunker sample needs the `$scope` because it is modifying the rows in the repeat directly.  your use case isn't the same;  it doesn't need the `$scope` because it isn't modifying a repeating item, it is modifying a single fixed item.  instead of passing `$scope`, pass `remark`, then modify `$scope.form_noteName` using that value.   that input is on the controller's scope, not on a child scope for each repeat.

Comment: Yes but all of this code is in a repeat itself^^ so i have many form_noteName not just one

Comment: how could it be inside the repeat?  that's not the code you are showing here....  are you saying that your `md-input-container` is a child inside the `md-menu-item`?

Comment: all that code i am showing here is in a big repeat itself thats what i meant. So there is not a single form_noteName but more on that page. Sorry if i mislead you

Comment: you really need to create a [mcve] of your situation, or at least show the relationship between these elements.  it sounds like now you are saying that the menu item and the input container each are repeating inside another repeater, which is still not the scope that you were trying to manipulate.

Comment: Ok i think this is one: http://plnkr.co/edit/1j3F64YyJPftxLf8QaZD?p=preview     I hope you can see what i want, i want the user to click on a reason and the reason should be automaticly added to the input field.

Comment: I think it works if i put the inputText in the myCollection object, but isn't there a more elegant way for this?

Comment: well, I'm guessing that you want to use `ng-change` in the dropdown and pass the selected item from the dropdown into the input box;  You can't use `ng-click` inside an `options` group.

Comment: why would you *not* want to put `inputText` in the `myCollection` object?  where else were you planning on storing the modified user results for later consumption?

Comment: I am afraid of the object to become to big. My idea was it to stay in the scope and later be passed to an Methode when the user had filled out everything...

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two ng-clicks. You need put both statements together separated by a semicolon, like this:

```
ng-click="addRemark(remark, this); testvariable='remark'"
```

Also you might not need the "this" since "remark" will give the particular element. However, I don't have enough of your code to be sure.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to delete it. The Problem is that i want the input field to be changed, thats why i pass the scope, because form_noteName is found in the scope. But it doesn't update the scope so my Input field isn't changed :/